# Enabling Users to Access File in Blocked Domain

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, webservices

We built an integration with Box.com. Sound files are stored in Box and then the public link to each file is stored on a record in Salesforce. The integration for this is done through Zapier. The url looks like https://companyname.box.com/filename.

The Box.com domain is being blocked by our user's company. I want to understand what I need to do to enable Salesforce to essentially make the request to Box.com for the user so the file is not blocked. User authentication is not needed as anyone can access. Unblocking the domain is not an option. The sound file would then open in a modal box or similar and play in the browser.

I'd assume this is some kind of web services but am very confused where to look to start. REST? SOAP? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Ajax_Proxy) can accomplish this task, or you can use a [@RemoteAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_RemoteAction.htm) to proxy through Visualforce, which is marginally less complicated than using the AJAX proxy and doesn't use API calls, but might not work with larger files. Once you have the raw data, convert it to a [data-uri](http://caniuse.com/#search=datauri), which will be supported by modern browsers. Note that you'll probably be limited to viewing images in Internet Explorer, but other browsers will happily convert the data-uri into a file you can download/save to your computer.

Comment: I might be more confused at the best/easiest options now. In addition to these 2 I've been told http://www.webdav.org/. These are sound files though so not sure about the data-uri option.